# Strategies in Scala

Tags: scala, haskell, parallel-processing

Is there an equivalent to Haskell `Control.Parallel.Strategies` or a way to achieve the same thing?

That allow an existing code to be evaluated in a different way.
By separating algorithm from strategy and algorithm from evaluation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Yes](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/concurrent/Strategy.scala), but only in [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/) and not in the standard library.